# Extracting text from images

Tags: c++, visual-c++, image-processing

Can anyone tell me how to read the text in an image by using vc++

Comment: Way more description required - also, why is it tagged as "html"?

Comment: If there is a jpg image of a soccer ball and the text "this is a soccer ball" at the bottom... you want to use c++ to return the text? Come on...

Comment: For cracking Captchas, I'm guessing?

Comment: Slow down a bit, people, this is a brand new user. Edit the question instead of downvoting so he gets an idea how to ask questions here.

Comment: @soulmerge: Agreed, let's not pick on the newbies

Comment: If you are talking about data encryption buried on images, then it's different. It involves a decryption algorithm that should be run on the image to get back the camouflaged text.

Alternatively, if you are talking about reading text in image headers of file formats like JPEG, BMP, etc. then it's a different question. Can you be a bit elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: From Other related posts teseract is a good bet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697852/c-c-objective-c-text-recognition-library

Answer (score 8):

The technology you are looking for is called "OCR", or ["Optical Character Recognition"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition).

Check out this codeproject entry:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/OCRwithMODI.aspx

It may help.

Alternatively, [this google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=OCR+visual+c%2B%2B) should take you a fair amount of the way.

Answer (score 1):

I've got no solution, but got this from a Google hit.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/paintlib/

Your question might be better answered if you augmented it with more information. I.e. Why do you want to do this? What image types are you wanting to read?

Give us a background of the requirements, or even motivation. You'll be more likely to get an informed answer.

Comment: Give us a link to an example image, that's even better.