# Is there any library in objective-c or c that will do OCR?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ocr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++/Objective-C text recognition library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697852/c-c-objective-c-text-recognition-library)

I want to develop an iPhone application that will take image as input and the output from will be text, simply OCR.
I want to know that is there is source, build-in library or free library which be helpful for this project.