# Classifying stroke input as text or drawing

Tags: ios, algorithm, machine-learning, classification

I'm interested in taking user stroke input (i.e. drawing with an iPad) and classifying it as either text or a drawing (or, I suppose, just non-text), in whatever capacity is reasonably feasible. I'm not expecting a pre-built library for this, I'm just having a hard time finding any papers or algorithmic resources about this.

I don't need to detect what the text is that they're drawing, just whether it's likely text or not.

Comment: By text, do you mean a letter or a word? I saw a paper two years ago that described an algorithm to find regions in arbitrary images that contain text-like features.

Comment: I can't see how you can 'detect if it's likely text or not' without an attempt to actually recognize the text, so maybe you should see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697852/c-c-objective-c-text-recognition-library

Comment: @piokuc I've seen evidence of it being done, I don't see why it would be impossible. It seems like a superset of actual text recognition.

Comment: Also note that I have stroke input, not just a bitmap, so I have direction of strokes, etc.

Comment: @aehlke I don't say it's impossible, just don't know how to do it :) Anyway, perhaps using one of the existing text recognition libraries is a way to go for you.

Comment: [Lipi Toolkit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lipitk/). might be useful

Answer (score 0):

I would think you will need to generate probabilities for what text character the input is. If the highest probability text character is below some threshold, classify the stroke as drawing.

This is a possible useful paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.0421v1.pdf (if only for its reference list).  Also the first hit on this google scholar search looks relevant: http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=classification+stroke+input+text+or+drawing